# Why don't my CSS static files work in Django when I pass an optional parameter to the view?

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-templates

I am making an application in Django, where I have a main (index) page displaying a number of objects styled with CSS. The CSS is in a static file. When I do not pass any parameters to the index view in views.py, all the CSS renders great. However, whenever I pass in an extra parameter to the view url, no CSS is applied (but the information gets displayed correctly). Please can someone help me with this?

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "auctions/static")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "auctions/static")]
```

urls.py (app):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("categories", views.categories, name="categories"),
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    **path("category/<str:cat_name>", views.index, name="index"),**
    path("create_listing", views.create_listing, name="create"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("<int:id>", views.view_listing, name="view"),
    path("watchlist", views.watchlist, name="watchlist")
]+static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT
```

Template:

```
{% load static %}
<link href="{% static 'auctions/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

views.py:

```
def index(request, cat_name=None):
    if cat_name is not None:
        listings = Listing.objects.filter(category=cat_name)
        listings = listings.filter(bid_active=True)
    else:
        listings = Listing.objects.filter(bid_active=True)
    return render(request, "auctions/index.html", {
            "listings": listings
            })
```

Basically, the view works if I don't enter the extra parameter (but I have to in order to avoid redundancy in my code).

Comment: I don't see your urls end in a trailing slash (e.g. `"categories"` should be `"categories/"`), do your urls even work or did you set `APPEND_SLASH = False` in the settings?

Answer (score 1):

you have them both named "index" in your url patterns. Name one of them 'index_with_category'. That's not going to solve your problem though. For that, look at the source in your browser and look to where your css is pointing.

When you specify a category, your url patterns matches the `category` path, it is looking for your `styles.css` in `/static_root/category/auctions/styles.css` but you want it to point to `/static_root/auctions/styles.css`. Since your url has the `category` in there, and there is no leading slash in the href to your css file, the browser is looking for `auctions` relative to `category`, which in some cases you may want, but probably not in this one. When you don't pass a category, your url is at the root of your site already so the relative reference to the `auctions` directory works.

I suspect you want to change that line to have a leading slash otherwise it will look for auctions relative to category:

```
<link href="{% static '/auctions/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

you wouldn't believe if I tell you that I only fail to type a slash (/)

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "auctions/static/")]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).